# Is there a conditional statement in yq?

Tags: jsonpath, yq

I want to use yq to this file

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <CA-CERT>
    server: https://master1:3078
  name: clusterA
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <CA-CERT>
    server: https://master1:3078
  name: clusterB
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null
```

I want to extract the certificate-authority-data of clusterB. So I write my code like this.
`yq -r 'clusters[?(@.name=="clusterB")].cluster.certificate-authority-data' ~/.kube/config`
But it didn't work for me. how to write it?

Is there no way to use yq like jq or jsonpath?

Comment: There are multiple implementations of `yq`. Which version are you using - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info. Post that version info to the question above